# Ubuntu 20.04 screen timeout is not working through command line

Tags: gui, gsettings

I am trying to lock GUI screen Ubuntu machine through gsettings and dconf, but I'm unable to do that. The terminal shows timeout values have changed, but in GUI leave remains old and the screen doesn't get locked.

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-delay 2

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 2

dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/screensaver/lock-delay "uint32 2"

dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/session/idle-delay  "uint32 2"

But when I see values on GUI in privacy tab the value remains unchanged as shown in the attachment.

[image: commandline]